# Index unmatched braces in LaTeX

Tags: braces, imakeidx

I am trying to make the following work

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
Let us try to index the characters '()'. \index{()@()} \\
Let us try to index the character '('. \index{(@(} \\
Let us try to index the character ')'. \index{)@)} \\
Let us try to index the characters '{}'. \index{\{\}@\{\}} 
Let us try to index the character '{'. \index{\{@\{} 
Let us try to index the character '}'. \index{\}@\}} 
\backmatter
\printindex
\end{document}
```

But seems like one cannot escape the characters `{` or `}` in makeidx.

The index file generated looks like this

```
\indexentry{()@()}{1}
\indexentry{(@(}{1}
\indexentry{)@)}{1}
\indexentry{\{\}@\{\}}{1}
\indexentry{\{@\{} Let us try to index the character '}'. \index{\}@\}{1}
```

What I expected was this -

```
\indexentry{()@()}{1}
\indexentry{(@(}{1}
\indexentry{)@)}{1}
\indexentry{\{\}@\{\}}{1}
\indexentry{\{@\{}{1}
\indexentry{\}@\}}{1}
```

How can I escape unmatched `}` and `{` in an index entry.

The unmatched `}` and `{` are used as I have a legacy True Type Devanagari font which has special glyphs for these characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation of MakeIndex](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/indexing/makeindex/doc/makeindex.pdf), page 6, says:

> Remember that the argument of an `\index` command must always have
>   matching braces, where the brace in a `\{` or `\}` command counts.

So, in your case, the matching braces `\{\}` are indexed well but the last two lines, which do not have matching braces, are the ones creating the problem.  You can easily wrap these with macros:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\def\lcurly{\{}
\def\rcurly{\}}
Let us try to index the characters '()'. \index{()@()} \\
Let us try to index the character '('. \index{(@(} \\
Let us try to index the character ')'. \index{)@)} \\
Let us try to index the characters '\{\}'. \index{\{\}@\{\}} \\
Let us try to index the character '\{'. \index{\lcurly@\lcurly} \\
Let us try to index the character '\}'. \index{\rcurly@\rcurly} 
\backmatter
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Furthermore, the braces that you had in quotes in your text should be escaped too.

Comment: A typo above - '\def\rcurly{\{}' should be changed to '\def\rcurly{\}}'. I cannot make the edit since an edit has to be at least 6 characters.

Comment: Sorry about that...  Copy-paste is a bad habit!  :-)
It has been fixed, thanks egreg.